# const details = await TutorBasic.findByIdAndUpdate({userId:tutorUserId},{detailsToUpdate},{new:true});

Tags: node.js

find the error it showing caste error

```
reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)   
      at new ObjectId (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:67:23)     
      at castObjectId (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:246:12)
      at SchemaType.applySetters (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1201:12)
      at SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1649:15)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1637:15)
      at SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1613:20)
      at cast (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:286:34)
      at Query.cast (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5351:12)    
      at castQuery (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5152:18)     
      at Query._findAndModify (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3984:23)
      at model.Query.<anonymous> (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3502:8)
      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:29:8)
      at D:\Phase1\tutortModule\tutorServer\node_modules\kareem\index.js:497:25
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11),
  valueType: 'Object'
}
```